# Can we do looping in a chain

Tags: spring-integration

We are facing a problem in one of the integration layer which is implemented in Spring Integration.

We need to implement the pagination logic in the integration layer.requirement is as follows

From integration layer we send the request to a mainframe system through IBM MQ and due to the MQ size issue the complete response data can not be retrieved in one call,so we need to implement the pagination logic.(send the multiple requests to mainframe system based on some flag in the response and aggregate the responses to build the final response )

We are not sure how to implement this requirement. any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance